# Norm of vectors inequality

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, inequality, normed-spaces

[image: How to Prove this]

I tried proving this with triangular inequality but i was not right can any one help me with this

Comment: Suggest improving the title to give a little more flavour to the question.  "How to prove this" could be *anything*...

Comment: Also, why not present your work so far?  It could be that your attempt goes wrong at a particular point, and it will be much more useful to you if people could point our where your error is.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: @user4140 Exactly,why the down votes ?

Comment: yes, that's what I just asked.

Comment: This is a relatively simple problem.  The fact that this had no title and no work (i.e. shows no real effort) goes against "Include *details* about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do."  There are always plenty of people who are happy to just dash off a solution, but IMO it would be good to see a bit more effort from the poster -- and willingness to put up partial work.

Comment: @AssadEbrahim The reason why i posted here is i got struck at one point.I was not sure if i was correct.

Comment: But he does kind of explain he tried using triangle inequality. And, he's a new user,perhaps he wasn't aware that title is very weak.

Comment: He's got his answers and I've expressed my opinion.  The community is more than welcome to express theirs -- in upvotes -- if they wish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We simply use the triangular inequality repeatedly:
$$
\|u\|=\|(u-v)+v\|\le \|u-v\|+\|v\|,
$$
and thus
$$
\|u\|-\|v\|\le \|u-v\|\le \|u\|+\|-v\|=\|u\|+\|v\|. \tag{1}
$$
Similarly
$$
\|v\|=\|(v-u)+u\|\le \|v-u\|+\|u\|,
$$
and thus
$$
\|v\|-\|u\|\le \|u-v\|. \tag{2}
$$
Now $(1)$ and $(2)$ imply that
$$
\big|\|u\|-\|v\|\big|\le \|u-v\|\le \|u\|+\|v\|.
$$

Answer (score 6):

The first

$$||u-v||=||u+(-v)||\le ||u||+||-v||=||u||+||v||$$
 and the second

$$||u||=||u-v+v||\le ||u-v||+||v||\Rightarrow ||u||-||v||\le ||u-v||$$
and by symmetry we have the other inequality so we conclude.

Comment: Are you the famous sami ben romdhane?

Comment: haha I don't know that there's a famous sami ben romdhane.

Comment: lol yeah, there's an entrepreneur with that name.

Comment: May be but I'm not so famous as this entrepreneur sami;-)

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

1. $\left\|u\right\| = \left\|(u-v)+v\right\|$
2. $\left\|v\right\| = \left\|(u-v)+u\right\|$
3. $\left\|u-v\right\| = \left\|u+(-v)\right\|$